# onDropdownRecyclerClick(int, java.lang.String) [cannot be applied to '(int)]

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, adapter

this is my code : [problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqT8f.jpg)

I used `onDropdownRecyclerClick(int, java.lang.String)` in `com.application.bris.ikurma_nos_gadai.page_aom.listener.DropdownRecyclerListener` cannot be applied to `(int)`, but i got that error, but when i commented on Create method `onDropdownRecyclerClick` in `DropdownRecyclerListener`, i got another error like this : [problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfZWo.jpg)

Comment: It would be better if you share the DropdownRecyclerview class to solve your problem.

Comment: below in the this comment, thank u sir

Comment: Instead of posting screenshot of your code copy paste the code inside [“code fences”](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) preferably using [syntax-highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). This makes it easier to read and isn't vulnerable to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Answer (score 0):

Your callback `onDropdownRecyclerClick` is clearly saying that you need two arguments, an int and a String.
So you just need to check what kind of data is that String (maybe it can be null) and just pass it